# Building a Sympy function to differential and integrate from Scipy interpolation

Tags: python, sympy, interpolation, calculus

During a project I've been working on, I collected experimental temperature data as a function of time from a metal casting at 4 locations in the sytsem. This temperature profile is complex with a period of initial cooling, followed by an enormous, sudden rise in temperature as the alloy arrives followed by a final period of cooling.

To understand the temperature environment between the measurement locations, I'm trying to use Python to solve the Heat equation which requires a combination of symbolic derivatives and integrals (for which I've used Sympy) and numerical calculations (which which I've used lambdify and numpy).

The issue comes when I want to use the collected temperature data as a boundary conditions in the calculation. I've use Scipy to interpolate between the data points to obtain a complete temperature data set for all times (and to obtain a new spline representing the derivative of the original spline) but I cannot obtain this interpolation response in a format the Sympy will understand for derivatives and integrals in the calculus

Any advice or suggestions?

########################################################################################################
The code I've used for the open step of defining the interpolation is detailed below. I appreciate it would be more efficiently written as a matrix, but I find it easier to see it all when its written out long hand (I generally simplify later if needed):
Note: The time (the x-axis parameter in the interpolation) is a strictly increasing parameter

```
import numpy as np                                             #import the relevant packages/items
from scipy import signal
import sympy as sp
from scipy.interpolate import *
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

x=sp.Symbol("x", real=True, positive=True)       #define the sympy symbols
L=sp.Symbol("L", real=True, positive=True)

filename='.../Temperature Data for Code.csv'
data = np.array(pd.read_csv(filename,skiprows=1, header=None))     #reading in the datasets from file

Time_exp=np.array(data[:,0])                           #assign the time (x-axis)  
T_Alloy_centre_orig=np.array(data[:,1]) +273           #assign 4 temperature (y-axis) and convert to K
T_Alloy_edge_orig=np.array(data[:,2]) +273
T_Inner_orig=np.array(data[:,9]) +273
T_Outer_orig=np.array(data[:,11]) +273

T_Alloy_centre=T_Alloy_centre_orig                #create copy of the original data before manipulation
T_Alloy_edge=T_Alloy_edge_orig
T_Inner=T_Inner_orig
T_Outer=T_Outer_orig

T_Alloy_centre=signal.savgol_filter(T_Alloy_centre,3,1)     #basic filter to smooth experimental noise
T_Alloy_edge=signal.savgol_filter(T_Alloy_edge,3,1)
T_Inner=signal.savgol_filter(T_Inner,3,1)
T_Outer=signal.savgol_filter(T_Outer,3,1)   

T_Alloy_centre_xt = UnivariateSpline(Time_exp, T_Alloy_centre,k=3)    #perform spline interpolation
T_Alloy_edge_xt = UnivariateSpline(Time_exp, T_Alloy_edge,k=3)
T_Inner_xt = UnivariateSpline(Time_exp, T_Inner,k=3)
T_Outer_xt = UnivariateSpline(Time_exp, T_Outer,k=3)

diff_T_Alloy_centre_xt = T_Alloy_centre_xt.derivative(n=1)     #new spline for derivative of previous
diff_T_Alloy_edge_xt = T_Alloy_edge_xt.derivative(n=1)
diff_T_Inner_xt = T_Inner_xt.derivative(n=1)
diff_T_Outer_xt = T_Outer_xt.derivative(n=1)
```

#############################################################################
here is where the speculation begins. I've tried several things to try and convert the resulting interpolation into something that can be used by Sympy but unsuccessfully.

1. First, I tried an sympy.implemented_function approach and just using lambda, although this just gave a string as far as I can tell:

   T_Alloy_centre_f = implemented_function('T_Alloy_centre_f', lambda t: T_Alloy_centre_xt)
   T_Alloy_centre_f  = lambda t: T_Alloy_centre_xt
2. Secondly, I tried using the interpolation functions available within Sympy (interpolating_spline) although this was running for 15 minutes without achieving a result for only one of the 4 measurements. It would be useful if this worked as it is already within Sympy, although the calculation time is extreme. Possibly as the data is not smooth, featuring a sudden, massive increase in temperature on arrival of the molten alloy.

   T_Alloy_centre_xt = sp.interpolating_spline(3, x, Time_exp, T_Alloy_centre)
3. Finally, to pulled the spline coefficients and knots out of the interpolation with the aim of building the function manually before converting, but I could not come up with a convenient way of getting the piecewise function. Nor did the previous implemented_function approach seem to work here either.

   spline_coeffs = T_Alloy_centre_xt.get_coeffs()
   spline_knots = T_Alloy_centre_xt.get_knots()

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I need something from this interpolation that can be passed through sp.diff and sp.integrate
###########################################################################
#if I can get past the above conversion, the next step in the code is evaluating the derivative at a specified value and performing an integral as below:

```
F_A=-1*sp.diff(T_Inner_f, t) - x/L*(sp.diff(T_Outer_f,t)-sp.diff(T_Inner_f,t))  
f_n_A=(2/L)*sp.integrate(F_A*sp.sin(lamda*x),(x,0,L))
```

Any assistance would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: I haven't tried to follow in detail what you are doing, but can comment on the joint use of numeric (scipy/numpy) and symbolic (sympy) code - it usually doesn't work.  scipy interpolation produces numpy arrays.  Arrays can't be used in sympy expressions.  sympy functions like `diff` and `integrate` work with sympy expressions, which are themselves built from sympy symbols.  Numeric values can be `subs` into expressions, but not arrays.  And expressions can be `lambdified`, producing python functions that work with arrays - but only for the most basic expressions.

Comment: Search on `[sympy]+[scipy]` to see the problems others have had.  By the way, we don't normally write `sympy functions`.  You can define a `function` analogous to a `symbol`, but that's not the same as a Python function.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Given how few examples I could find on implementing them together, I started to assume they were not particularly cooperative with each other.

Having continued to look into it over this afternoon, I've become more interested in the interpolation models within Sympy, but I have never used these.